# Error : Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object when upgraded magento from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento

I had magento site which was based on community edition 1.5 when i upgraded it to 1.7 the error came up : "Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object..."
Have tried almost every solution but couldn't make it working.

The full error-message is:

```
Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object in /site-path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 434
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the full error message, including the 'file' that the error occurs in and the line number.

Comment: full error : Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object in /site-path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 434

Comment: Can you confirm that app/etc/config.xml  is not missing and please post the code of the method found around that line 434.

Comment: Yes i have already checked that config.xml is present.

Answer (score 4):

Is your webshop using Aitoc Extensions ?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/279027/

You need to re-install or upgrade the extensions but what you can do in the meanwhile is:

comment App/Mage.php line 198

```
//self::$_appRoot = null;
```

Because this line is called on:
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php line 54:

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello khoekman, thanks for the reply but i have already tried this and i didn't found any AITOC extension in my site. It would be very helpful if you can suggest me by which Namespace and module name AITOC extensions exists .

Comment: Thanks @khoekman Phew!!! I was going crazy. I should never put a site live on late friday :(

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a
>   non-object. In the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php.

**comment App/Mage.php line 198
//self::$_appRoot = null;**